# TYPO3 Localizer Extension - Cart Configuration

Tags: localization, typo3, content-management-system, typo3-extensions

So I am trying to learn a bit more about TYPO3 and Localization. So I am using the Extensions:

- L10N-Manager
- Localizer

I can create the base Localizer-Configuration but whenever I go into the Selector Tab and try to create a new Cart, I can't select any languages - which makes the created Cart "breaking" (a "global cart" is created but all fields are not available for editing and I can't view it in the Cart Tab of the Localizer)

[image]

I am wondering what I am doing wrong - I sadly didn't find any records on such problems or a better introduction about the configuration. All Tutorials just show how the Localizer Configuration is created and then they can simply create a cart.

Is this a known problem? Would be great if anybody knows a solution. Or a really good tutorial that shows step by step how to set up the configuration.

Info: I am using TYPO3 on my localhost (XAMPP) with TYPO3 Version: 10.4.13

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 0):

The Localizer manual says for both, source and target language fields:

> Important
>
> Make sure each of the language records has been configured with the
> necessary locales to distinguish between languages during the
> translations process.

So did you configure the language records accordingly?

Most likely the locale values based on static_info_tables records have not been set, which is currently still necessary. So you should check your sys_language records for those values.

In upcoming versions of Localizer this will be replaced with values taken from the site configuration.